# My Visual Studio is showing random "formatting errors"

Tags: unity-game-engine, formatting, code-formatting

In the image below you can see my problem, I´m stuck with this problem for like 1 week now.
I cant work properly with these. ;(
Are there any solutions to this?
I tried deleting the .suo file and reinstalled Visaul Studio but nothing helped.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOveflow! Your `image below` seems to be missing! Please add it to your question. In general make sure to go through [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: should be done now :)

Comment: Are you using some custom CodeCop / ReSharper like extension? It looks like you are getting errors because there is unused whitespace (tab/spaces but no code in `Start` and `Update`) and the methods are empty ... not something VisualStudio would do by default afaik actually ... I know that ReSharper e.g. would at least hint or warn about it but you can easily adjust the severity of each hint/warning into an error and vice versa

Comment: How can i do that ? Im new into programming

Comment: And its on every file that i got in my project it doenst work if i supress the error

Comment: Well if it is e.g. ReSharper you would hit `CTRL` + `.`  and should see a list with possible fixes .. then you would change the severity for this type of issue to hint or none instead of error ...

Comment: thanks but i already fixed it but i just exported my assets into a new project :-: